# How should I find the general solution of the Euler-Lagrange equations for $(z_{1}, z_{2})$?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Let the two coupled Euler-Lagrange equations giving the stationary path of the functional $S[y_{1}, y_{2}]=\int [y_{1}'^2+2y_{2}'^2+(2y_{1}+y_{2})^2]dx$ be $y_{1}''-2(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$ and $2y_{2}''-(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$. By making the linear transformation $z_{1}=y_{1}+ay_{2}, z_{2}=2y_{1}+y_{2}$ to the new dependent variables $(z_{1}, z_{2})$, where $a$ is a constant, the value of $a$ such that the functional can be written as the sum of two functionals, one of which depends only on $z_{1}$ and the other only on $z_{2}$ is $-4$.

a) Find the general solution of the Euler-Lagrange equations for $(z_{1}, z_{2})$, and hence find the general solution for $(y_{1}, y_{2})$.

b) Verify by direct substitution that your general solution for $(y_{1}, y_{2})$ satisfies the two coupled Euler-Lagrange equations giving the stationary path of the functional $S[y_{1}, y_{2}]=\int [y_{1}'^2+2y_{2}'^2+(2y_{1}+y_{2})^2]dx$.

I know that the Euler-Lagrange equation is $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'})-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0, y(a)=A, y(b)=B$ for the functional $S[y]=\int_{a}^{b}F(x, y, y')dx, y(a)=A, y(b)=B$, but how should I find the Euler-Lagrange equations for $z_{1}=y_{1}+ay_{2}, z_{2}=2y_{1}+y_{2}$?

Comment: I can see that $S[y_{1}, y_{2}]=\int (z_{1}'^2-2az_{1}'y_{2}'+a^2y_{2}'^2+2z_{2}'^2-8z_{2}'y_{1}'+8y_{1}'^2+4y_{1}^2+4y_{1}y_{2}+y_{2}^2)dx$. But I found out that the Euler-Lagrange equation for $z_{1}$ is $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial z_{1}'})-\frac{\partial F}{\partial z_{1}}=0\implies z_{1}''=0$ and the Euler-Lagrange equation for $z_{2}$ is $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial z_{2}'})-\frac{\partial F}{\partial z_{2}}=0\implies z_{2}''=0$. Are these correct?

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange equation for $z_{1}$ is $\frac{2}{9}z_{1}''=0$ and the Euler-Lagrange equation for $z_{2}$ is $\frac{4}{9}z_{2}''-2z_{2}=0$. Are these correct?

Comment: So the general solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation for $z_{1}$ is $z_{1}=\frac{9}{2}(c_{1}x+c_{2})$ and the general solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation for $z_{2}$ is $z_{2}=c_{1}e^{\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}}t+c_{2}e^{-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}}t$. Are these correct?

Comment: Since the Euler-Lagrange equations for $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ are $y_{1}''-2(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$ and $2y_{2}''-(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$, how should I find the general solution for $(y_{1}, y_{2})$?

Comment: In the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814420/how-should-i-find-the-value-of-a-such-that-the-functional-can-be-written-as-th) I mentioned before, it was shown that $y_1=\frac{-z_1+az_2}{2a-1}=\frac{z_1+4z_2}{9}$ and $y_2=\frac{2z_1-z_2}{2a-1}=\frac{-2z_1+z_2}{9}$. Now make the substitutions $z_1=c_1x+c_2$ and $z_2=c_3e^{\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}x}+c_4e^{-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}x}$ in those expressions.

Comment: So I've got $y_{1}=\frac{c_{1}x+c_{2}+4(c_{3}e^{\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}x}+c_{4}e^{-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}x})}{9}$ and $y_{2}=\frac{-2(c_{1}x+c_{2})+(c_{3}e^{\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}x}+c_{4}e^{-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}x})}{9}$. Are these the correct general solutions of the Euler-Lagrange equations for $(y_{1}, y_{2})$?

Comment: I don't know. You have to check whether they solve the equations $y_{1}''-2(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$ and $2y_{2}''-(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$.

Comment: I checked and found out that they solve those equations. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem. Now I suggest that you [answer your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

By considering the functional $S[z_{1}, z_{2}]=\frac{1}{9}(\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}}z_{1}'^2dx+\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}}(2z_{2}'^2+9z_{2}^2)dx)$ and applying the definition of the Euler-Lagrange equation, we have that the Euler-Lagrange euqation for $z_{1}$ is $\frac{2}{9}z_{1}''=0$ and the Euler-Lagrange equation for $z_{2}$ is $\frac{4}{9}z_{2}''-2z_{2}=0$.

From here after integrating, we can see that the general solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation for $z_{1}$ is $z_{1}=\frac{9}{2}(c_{1}x+c_{2})$ and the general solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation for $z_{2}$ is $z_{2}=c_{3}e^{\frac{3x}{\sqrt{2}}}+c_{4}e^{-\frac{3x}{\sqrt{2}}}$.

Note that the Euler-Lagrange equation for $y_{1}$ is $y_{1}''-2(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$ and the Euler-Lagrange equation for $y_{2}$ is $2y_{2}''-(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$.

The general solution for $(y_{1}, y_{2})$ is $y_{1}=\frac{c_{1}x+c_{2}+4(c_{3}e^{\frac{3x}{\sqrt{2}}}+c_{4}e^{-\frac{3x}{\sqrt{2}}})}{9}$ and $y_{2}=\frac{-2(c_{1}x+c_{2})+c_{3}e^{\frac{3x}{\sqrt{2}}}+c_{4}e^{-\frac{3x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{9}$.

By direct substitution, we have $0=0$.